# limit of a function that includes floor function

Tags: calculus

What is the value of these limits;

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{+}}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}{\lfloor x\rfloor-x}$

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^{-}}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor-1}{\lfloor x\rfloor-x}$

Comment: ı make the transformation $x=1+h$ and take limit as $h\rightarrow 0^{+}$ but ı confuse in the process

Answer (score 4):

1) We may suppose that $1\lt x\lt 2$. So we have $\lfloor x\rfloor =1$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor=1 \not= x$, so 
$$\lim_{x\to1+}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor -1}{\lfloor x\rfloor-x}=\lim_{x\to1+}\frac{0}{1-x}=\lim_{x\to1+}0=0.$$

2) We may suppose that $0\lt x\lt1$. So we have $\lfloor x\rfloor=0$, so 
$$\lim_{x\to1-}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor -1}{\lfloor x\rfloor-x}=\lim_{x\to1-}\frac{0-1}{0-x}=\lim_{x\to1-}\frac{1}{x}=1.$$

Note that $x\to \alpha$ does not mean $x=\alpha$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Look at the following figures. While $x\to 1^+$ then in a very small neighborhood of $x=1$ from the right we have: $$x\to1^+\longrightarrow x\in [1,1+\epsilon)\to \lfloor x\rfloor=1$$

[image]

[image]